# Git not ignoring particular file

Tags: git

When I run git status I still see files that are suppose to be ignored.

My `.gitignore` looks like the following:

```
/bin/
/build/

*.class
*.classpath
*.settings
```

When I run `git status` I still see `modified: build/dist/version.txt` under the unstaged section.

All the other files that were generated under the build folder were ignored except `version.txt`.

Comment: If you were tracking this file before, I'm pretty sure you have to untrack it somehow, maybe deleting it from repo using `git rm` or something like that. I'll try finding the exact answer later

Comment: try [this](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/01/Untrack-files-already-added-to-git-repository-based-on-gitignore/), it seems promissing